# Why am I getting this error in my JAVA code?

Tags: java, arrays, loops, birthday-paradox

> The birthday paradox says that the probability that two people in a room
>   will have the same birthday is more than half as long as the number of
>   people in the room (n), is more than 23. This property is not really a paradox,
>   but many people ﬁnd it surprising. Design a C++ program that can
>   test this paradox by a series of experiments on randomly generated birthdays,
>   which test this paradox for n =5, 10, 15, 20, . . . , 100. You should run
>   at least 10 experiments for each value of n and it should output, for each
>   n, the number of experiments for that n, such that two people in that test
>   have the same birthday.

```
package birth;
import java.util.Random;

/* Question: 
The birthday paradox says that the probability that two people in a room
will have the same birthday is more than half as long as the number of
people in the room (n), is more than 23. This property is not really a paradox,
but many people ﬁnd it surprising. Design a C++ program that can
test this paradox by a series of experiments on randomly generated birthdays,
which test this paradox for n =5, 10, 15, 20, . . . , 100. You should run
at least 10 experiments for each value of n and it should output, for each
n, the number of experiments for that n, such that two people in that test
have the same birthday.
*/

public class birth {

public static final int YEAR = 365;

public static void main(String[] args)
{

    int numOfPeople = 5;
    int people = 5;

    //DOB array
    int[] birthday = new int[YEAR];



    //Creates an array that represents 365 days
    for (int i = 0; i < birthday.length; i++)
        birthday[i] = i + 1;

    //Random Number generator
    Random randNum = new Random();

    int iteration = 1;

    //iterates around peopleBirthday array
    while (numOfPeople <= 100)
    {
        System.out.println("Iteration: " + iteration);
        System.out.println();
        //Creates array to holds peoples birthday
        int[] peopleBirthday = new int[numOfPeople];


        //Assigns people DOB to people in the room
        for (int i = 0; i < peopleBirthday.length; i++)
        {
            int day = randNum.nextInt(YEAR + 1);
            peopleBirthday[i] = birthday[day];


        }
        for (int i = 0; i < peopleBirthday.length; i++)
        {   


            //stores value for element before and after
            int person1 = peopleBirthday[i];
            int person2 = i + 1;

            //Checks if people have same birthday
            for (int j = person2; j < peopleBirthday.length; j++)
            {


                //Prints matching Birthday days
                if (person1 == peopleBirthday[j])
                {
                    System.out.println("P1: " + person1 + " P2: " + peopleBirthday[j]);
                    System.out.println("Match!!! \n");

                }
            }
        }


        //Increments the number of people in the room
        numOfPeople += 5;
        iteration++;
    }

    }
}
```

I am getting a error: `java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: 365` I can't figure out what is wrong with my code

Comment: `Design a C++ program...` but your code is in `Java`. Oops

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It would be nice if you provided the exact line number where the exception was thrown (the information is in the error stack trace that you got), but it's very likely that the problem occurs here:

```
int day = randNum.nextInt(YEAR + 1); // 365 + 1 = 366
peopleBirthday[i] = birthday[day];
```

The documentation for [Random.nextInt](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Random.html#nextInt-int-) says:

> **Returns:** the next pseudorandom, uniformly distributed int value between zero (inclusive) and bound (exclusive) from this random number generator's sequence.

In this case, you are calling `Random.nextInt` with a value of `366` (`365 + 1`), so that means that you are effectively reading some random number between `0` and `365`.  If you ever do get `365`, that will make `birthday[day]` throw the out of bounds exception, as the maximum index of your array is `364`, not `365`.

You probably meant to read the random value this way instead:

```
int day = randNum.nextInt(YEAR); // 365 (exclusive)
```

Answer (score 1):

Arrays in Java are zero based. If you create `birthday` with a length of `365`, the indexes would be from `0` to `364`.

You need to change this line from this:

```
int[] birthday = new int[YEAR];
```

To this:

```
int[] birthday = new int[YEAR+1];
```

Comment: Thank you! That solved my problem completely! I appreciate the help!

Comment: It doesn't quite solve the problem, although it makes your program run.  As @sstan noted, you're generating random values from 0 to 365--that is, 366 different random values.  So your experiments won't match the original problem; they would be valid for a year with 366 days, rather than a year with 365 days.  (Which is OK if you want to count February 29, but the way the problem is usually stated, it doesn't count for that.  Besides, if you want to include February 29 you have to weight it since 2/29 birthdays only occur 97/400 times as often as other days.)

Comment: Oh i see! That makes sense. Thank you for the help. I appreciate it.